# Jquery or PHP Highlight a table row based on the repeated values

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table which displays data fetched from the database. I have done this in PHP say `$data_array()`;
What I want is to find the record with same Email address and highlight those rows with Red. Meaning, if an email address is repeated in the table twice or thrice, all the 3 rows will get Red highlighted.

I have done this way:

```
$exist = array();
foreach($data_array as $da){
    if(in_array($da['Email'], $exist)){
        $row_color = "#f00";   //  Red
    }else{
        $row_color = "#fff";   // White
    }
    echo "<tr style='color:".$row_color.";'>";
        echo "<td>".$da['Email']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $exist[] = $da['Email'];
}
```

The above works and displays the second and the third row highlighted but not the first one. Obviously my code has nothing which will highlight the first record which has repeated value.

How can I do this? Can be done in PHP or Jquery also. Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `jQuery`, you can use `filter()` and use `includes()` to check if `<td>`'s text is in the array.

```js
var emails = ['email1@bla.com', 'select@bla.com'];

$('table td').filter(function() {
  return emails.includes($(this).text().trim());
}).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>email1@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>doNotSelect@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>email1@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>doNotSelectToo@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>someOtherEmail@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select@bla.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I used your jquery and also mixed a little PHP to get the end result. `if(in_array($da['Email'], $exist)){ $in_array_email[] = $da['Email']; }`
Used this array in Jquery to highlight the  columns. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the duplicate-check from the rendering of the HTML and do it beforehand, so that you know whether an email is duplicated when you are rendering your HTML.

**Example**

```
<?php
$data_array = [
  [ 'Email' => 'test@example.com' ],
  [ 'Email' => 'test2@example.com' ],
  [ 'Email' => 'test@example.com' ],
  [ 'Email' => 'test@example.com' ],
];
$email_count = [];

// Count emails.
foreach($data_array as $entry) {
    $email = $entry['Email'];

    if (isset($email_count[$email])) {
            $email_count[$email]++;
    } else {
            $email_count[$email] = 1;
    }
}

// Render table.
foreach($data_array as $entry) {
    if($email_count[$entry['Email']] > 1){
        $row_color = "#f00";   //  Red
    }else{
        $row_color = "#fff";   // White
    }
    echo "<tr style='color:".$row_color.";'>";
    echo "<td>".$entry['Email']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Result**

```
<tr style='color:#f00;'><td>test@example.com</td></tr>
<tr style='color:#fff;'><td>test2@example.com</td></tr>
<tr style='color:#f00;'><td>test@example.com</td></tr>
<tr style='color:#f00;'><td>test@example.com</td></tr>
```